# How to check the service status under other user managed by systemd?

Tags: systemd

For example, i have two users: `user1` and `user2`. Under `user1` we run a `service1` service managed by systemd. Under `user2` we run a `service2` service managed by systemd.

Currently, we only allow `user1` to login a machine, How do i run `systemd status` or `systemd is-active` to tell whether `service2` is **running** or not.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
sudo systemctl status service2
```

If necessary, add the appropriate entry to /etc/sudoers to limit user1 to only using sudo to call this specific command.

Comment: I use the same pattern, it can work. Root and those who `sudo` to root can get the status of any command via `systemctl`. If there's a problem with the attempting to use `sudo`, you should add it to your question or ask a new question about that.